# Datatable loading

Tags: jquery, datatable, loading

I am using a jquery datatable to display records. I am fetching around 12000 records from database and appending it to html table and then converting it to jQuery datatable.

The conversion to datatable takes a very long time. I waited for around 15mins but still the table is not loaded.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest using `pagination` and displaying only few records at a time, have a look at: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination.  Displaying 12000 record at once, I don't this really provides good user experience.  Use ajax and pagination to load your data for each page.

Comment: For such a large number of rows [server side processing](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side) is a better option. Only pagination wont make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for the lag is the huge amount of HTML elements you are trying to display on your page that corresponds to 12000 records, the only solution is to reduce that as max as you can.

1. Do not place records in html, send them to your page via JSON - you can load it as a `<script>` or via ajax or else...
2. Limit the records per page for your datatable. First enable paging `bPaginate: true`, second set records per-page `iDisplayLength: 25`
3. Use `yourDataTable.fnAddData(data)` to load the dataset into it.

Answer (score 1):

Trust **Indexing** has been enabled on key columns used by the query.
Also despite appending the result in HTML and converting to DataTable, I would advise the following

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: url_to_data,
      dataSrc: "",                  
      contentType: "application/json",
      type: "POST",
      data : function(d) {
          return JSON.stringify({ param1: param1_val, param2: param2_val });
      },
   },
   pageLength: 30,
   processing: true,
   serverSide: true, //server side processing for larger datasets
   columns: [
      { sTitle: "col_1", data: "col_1_field" },
      { sTitle: "col_2", data: "col_2_field" },
   ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dataTables.scrollingPagination.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "sPaginationType": "scrolling",
                 "bProcessing": true

            } );
        } );
    </script>
```

Comment: i am using "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"..
this only differs in the type of pagination but not the time for loading data

Answer (score 0):

This is old but useful...I use the following to display a loading gif for my long loading data.  Use this in conjunction with pagination.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
 #dvLoading
 {
  background:#000 url(http://mfgweb.binney.com/manuf/all_data    
 /img/loader2.gif) no-repeat center center;
   height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1000;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
 }

</style>

<script>
$(window).load(function(){
$('#dvLoading').fadeOut(500);
});
</script>
<div id="dvLoading"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's taking time to load as there will be two iterations- ***one to iterate and load the content in HTML and the other to make a datatable out of it***. Instead directly load the datatable from server using parameters like this:

```
       "sAjaxSource": '#yourServerCallHereWhichReturnsJSON#',
       "fnServerData": fnServerObjectToArray(aPublicationElements),
```

Here "aPublicationElements" is a variable to contain JSON elements like this:

> var aPublicationElements = [ 'jsonParameter1','jsonParameter2','jsonParameter3','jsonParameter4'] ;

And render those data inside parameters like this:

```
       "aoColumns": [
                        {"sTitle":"Title1",
                            "render": function(data, type, oObj) {
                                return oObj[0];
                            }   
                        },
                        {"sTitle":"Title2",
                            "render": function(data, type, oObj) {
                                return oObj[1];
                            }   
                        },
                        {"sTitle":"Title3",
                            "render": function(data, type, oObj) {
                                return oObj[2];
                            }   
                        },
                        {"sTitle":"Title4",
                            "render": function(data, type, oObj){
                                return oObj[3];
                            }
                        }
                        }
                    ],
```

The function "fnServerObjectToArray" is something like this to convert server object to array:

```
fnServerObjectToArray = function ( aElements ){
    return function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        $.ajax({
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "POST",
            "url": sSource,
            "data": aoData,
            "success": function (json) {
                var a = [];
                for ( var i=0, iLen=json.length ; i<iLen ; i++ ) {
                    var inner = [];
                    for ( var j=0, jLen=aElements.length ; j<jLen ; j++ ) {
                        inner.push( json[i][aElements[j]] );
                    }
                    a.push( inner );
                }
                json.aaData = a;
                fnCallback(json);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try Datatable ServerSide...
[Follow this link](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, it could be useful for the op, however links tend to get broken overtime.... pls consider copy-pasting the main reasons why using datatable serverside is a good idea (or you can put it in your own words as well). Thanks.

Comment: For large databases this will be helpful. It will not retrieve all data from database on processing. For more https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html